Which goodness of fit test to test a sample of size one?
I have a sample of integers in the range 1 to 16. They are drawn iid from some unspecified distribution. If I am then given one more integer drawn independently from a possibly different distribution, what is a suitable goodness of fit test to reject the null hypothesis that it is drawn from the same distribution as the first set of integers?
I thought about using a Chi squared test but I don’t know if that is suitable when the second sample is of size one.

It would help (immensely) to specify an alternate hypothesis: do you have one in mind?

???maybe??? just the sample frequency, i.e. the observed proportion of your reference sample that is equal to the new integer? That seems to make some sense but I don't know if it would have the desired properties ... it doesn't seem that you have much else to use, though ...

Does the alternative distribution have the same support of [1, 16]?

@dimitriy yes it does

When you say different distribution, do you mean you want to test if they are from different distribution families (i.e. binomial vs. poisson) or from the same family with a different mean probability?

About the only approach which comes to mind is to look at the proportion of this single value in your sample, or rather at the confidence interval (CI) of that proportion. Let's call this single integer value, also defined over [1,16] as $k$. Compute (via binomial confidence interval: how many $k's$ out of the total sample) the CI for the proportion of $k's$ in your sample. Compute a single sided, upper bound CI. If that upper bound is, say, less than 5% (assuming you will be using the "traditional" 95% significance level; otherwise adjust as needed), then you are 95% confident that this value $k$ did nto come from the same distribution (because your probability of getting $k$ from the same distribution as your sample is less than 5%). That upper bound would in fact be your "p-value" (the probability of observing this single datapoint, $k$, under the null hypothesis, i.e. if it came from the same distribution as the sample).
Btw, $\chi^2$ would not even compute, because one of the values is 0 (number of non-$k$'s in your sample of one).

Would a two sided test be suitable too?

If the second sample is of size 3 instead, would I need a completely different method?

Two-sided test would not be recommended: the low bound does not tell you anything; you do not care if the proportion of $k$'s could be as low as e.g. 3%. You only care how high it might be (you got 100% $k$'s in the 2nd sample...). Yes, you would need a different if your 2nd sample is of size 3, because the datapoints in the 2nd sample may now not all have the same value. In effect, the problem becomes even harder.

I think you will have issues with power, so only very extreme observations will be separable. If you can get more draws from the second group, that should help. Both approaches below are compatible with enlarging that group.
The simplest thing would be a two-sample Wilcoxon rank-sum (Mann–Whitney) test or a permutation test. The intuition for the latter is explained here.
Here's an example in Stata, with $N_{g=0} = 19$ and $N_{g=1} = 1$:
. clear

. set seed 8132024

. set obs 20
Number of observations (_N) was 0, now 20.

. gen group = cond(_n == _N,1,0)

. gen draw = ceil(16 * uniform()) if group == 0
(1 missing value generated)

. replace draw = 16 if group == 1
(1 real change made)

. assert inrange(draw,1,16) if group == 0

. table group, stat(min draw) stat(max draw) stat(mean draw) stat(freq) nototal

-------------------------------------------------------------
      |  Minimum value   Maximum value       Mean   Frequency
------+------------------------------------------------------
group |                                                      
  0   |              3              16   9.578947          19
  1   |             16              16         16           1
-------------------------------------------------------------

. // (1) Tests
. permute group (diff:_b[1.group]), enumerate nowarning : reg draw i.group, vce(robust)
(running regress on estimation sample)
(enumerating all 20 possible permutations)

Permutations (20): ..........10..........20 done

Enumeration permutation results

Number of observations = 20
Number of permutations = 20

Permutation variable: group

      Command: regress draw i.group, vce(robust)
  [diff]_pm_1: _b[1.group]

----------------------------------------------------------
           T |    T(obs)       Test       c       n      p
-------------+--------------------------------------------
diff         |
       _pm_1 |  6.421052      lower      20      20 1.0000
             |                upper       4      20  .2000
             |            two-sided                  .4000
----------------------------------------------------------
Notes: For lower one-sided test, c = #{T <= T(obs)} and p = p_lower = c/n.
       For upper one-sided test, c = #{T >= T(obs)} and p = p_upper = c/n.
       For two-sided test, p = 2*min(p_lower, p_upper).

. ranksum draw, by(group) exact porder

Two-sample Wilcoxon rank-sum (Mann–Whitney) test

       group |      Obs    Rank sum    Expected
-------------+---------------------------------
           0 |       19       191.5       199.5
           1 |        1        18.5        10.5
-------------+---------------------------------
    Combined |       20         210         210

Unadjusted variance       33.25
Adjustment for ties       -0.50
                     ----------
Adjusted variance         32.75

H0: draw(group==0) = draw(group==1)
         z = -1.398
Prob > |z| = 0.1621
Exact prob = 0.4000

P{draw(group==0) > draw(group==1)} = 0.079

If you draw a 16 at the end, the p-value on the null of no difference is 0.4. But the second test also returns a probability that a random draw from group 0 exceeds group 1 of $0.079$. This can be informative.
Another option would be a two-class finite mixture model, where the probability of class membership depends on the group. I would look at the predicted latent class posterior probability for the last observation:
. // (2) Two-Class Finite Mixture Model
. fmm 2, lcprob(i.group) nolog: regress draw

Finite mixture model                                        Number of obs = 20
Log likelihood = -54.027822

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
1.Class      |  (base outcome)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
2.Class      |
     1.group |   20.06348   19288.67     0.00   0.999    -37785.04    37825.17
       _cons |  -.3290718   .5806215    -0.57   0.571    -1.467069    .8089254
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Class:    1      
Response: draw   
Model:    regress

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
draw         |
       _cons |   6.437461   .9593273     6.71   0.000     4.557214    8.317708
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
  var(e.draw)|   4.973732   3.508829                      1.247911    19.82354
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Class:    2      
Response: draw   
Model:    regress

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
draw         |
       _cons |   14.17423   .8361351    16.95   0.000     12.53544    15.81303
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
  var(e.draw)|   3.446671   2.238416                      .9651462    12.30854
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. predict p_class1, classpr

. predict pp_class1, classposteriorpr 

. sort group draw

. list, noobs sepby(group) abbr(20)

  +-------------------------------------+
  | group   draw   p_class1   pp_class1 |
  |-------------------------------------|
  |     0      3   .5815336    .9999999 |
  |     0      4   .5815336    .9999995 |
  |     0      4   .5815336    .9999995 |
  |     0      5   .5815336    .9999947 |
  |     0      6   .5815336    .9999456 |
  |     0      7   .5815336    .9994899 |
  |     0      7   .5815336    .9994899 |
  |     0      7   .5815336    .9994899 |
  |     0      8   .5815336    .9956377 |
  |     0      9   .5815336    .9667346 |
  |     0     10   .5815336     .801788 |
  |     0     12   .5815336    .0928722 |
  |     0     12   .5815336    .0928722 |
  |     0     12   .5815336    .0928722 |
  |     0     14   .5815336    .0036868 |
  |     0     14   .5815336    .0036868 |
  |     0     16   .5815336     .000191 |
  |     0     16   .5815336     .000191 |
  |     0     16   .5815336     .000191 |
  |-------------------------------------|
  |     1     16   2.69e-09    3.69e-13 |
  +-------------------------------------+

Here, it is very unlikely that the 16 from group 1 belongs to the first class. This approach makes the assumption that there really are two distinct classes, but it gets you sharper results.
